# Error at backbone model fetch to slim framework

Tags: backbone.js, cordova, slim

I'm trying to get a simple app working. It uses backbone, the slim framework and cordova. For now, all i'm trying to do is fetch user models from a MySQL database. Client side code looks like:

```
// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady()
{
    // This little code snippet prepends our root to any Ajax call.
    $.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
        options.url = 'http://localhost/~nmeibergen/IBMI/www/' + options.url;
    });

    var profileView = new ProfileView();

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
          "": "home"
        }
    });

    var router = new Router();
    router.on('route:home', function() {
        profileView.render();   
    });

    Backbone.history.start();
}

var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'index.php/users',
    model: User
});

var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'index.php/users',

    defaults: {
        user_id: 1,
        name: 'Nathan',
    }
});

var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#home',

    render: function () {
        var users = new Users();
        alert('all fine');
        users.fetch();
    }
});
```

Whenever I simply go to `http://localhost/~nmeibergen/IBMI/www/index.php/users`, I get the expected JSON object:

```
[{"user_id":"1","name":"Jhonathan "},{"user_id":"0","name":"Nathan"}]
```

However when running the above code it hits the alert 'all fine', but then gives me the following error and stack trace:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'targetModel.prototype') in backbone.js:1:689
            set        backbone.js:1:689
            success    backbone.js:1:686
            fire       jquery-1.11.1.js:3119
            fireWith   jquery-1.11.1.js:3231
            done       jquery-1.11.1.js:9275
            callback   jquery-1.11.1.js:9685
```

I can't seem to find out what is wrong with the code, it should be pretty basic. Thank you for looking!

Comment: @muistooshort: I just edited my question including the stack trace in a non-minified Backbone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say this:

```
var x = 6;
```

The `var x` declaration will be hoisted to the top of the current scope. However, the assignment part will **not** be hoisted. The result is that you're saying this:

```
var x;
// Everything from the top of the scope to your `var x = 6` goes here.
x = 6;
```

In your case, you're doing this:

```
var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'index.php/users',
    model: User
});

var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'index.php/users',

    defaults: {
        user_id: 1,
        name: 'Nathan',
    }
});
```

so `var User` is hoisted to the top of the scope but `User = Backbone.Model.extend(...)` happens *after* `Users = Backbone.Collection.extend(...)`. Rearranging the code to match what really happens, we have:

```
var Users, User;

Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    //...
    model: User
});
User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    //...
});
```

What do you think the value of `User` will be when it is used in the definition of `Users`? `User` will be `undefined` just like any other uninitialized variable.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/xYkmc/

You need to define your `User` before `Users`:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'index.php/users',

    defaults: {
        user_id: 1,
        name: 'Nathan',
    }
});

var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'index.php/users',
    model: User
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/E7V84/

Comment: thanks, thanks a lot! These are great insides of which I would love to know more. It solved to problem:):)